# Cannot use import statement outside a module in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I was working on the project on model.js file, then after that I need to import model.js file to Shareplace.js file. But after that the problem occurs into the console browser "Cannot use import statement outside a module".

**This is my Shareplace.js file code:-**

```
import {modal} from '../src/UI/modal';  

class PlaceFinder
{
    constructor()
    {
        const AddressForm = document.querySelector('form');
        const locateUserButton = document.getElementById('locate-btn');
        
        locateUserButton.addEventListener('click',this.locateUserHandler);
        
        AddressForm.addEventListener('submit',this.findAddressHandler);
    }
    locateUserHandler()
    {
        if(!navigator.geolocation)
        {
            alert("Location feature isn't available in your browser - please use a more modern browser or manually enter an address.");
            return;
        }
        const Modal = new modal('loading-modal-content','Loading location,please wait!');
        modal.show();
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        successResult => 
        {
            modal.hide();
            console.log(successResult);
            const coordinates = 
            {
                latitude:successResult.coords.latitude + Math.random() * 50,
                longkey:successResult.coords.longitude + Math.random() * 50,

            };
            console.log(coordinates);
        },
        error =>
        {
            modal.hide();
            alert("Could'nt locate you unfortunately,Please enter an address manually!");
        });
    }

    findAddressHandler()
    {

    }
}

const placeFinder = new PlaceFinder();
```

**This is my webpack.config.js file:-**

```
const path = require('path');
const CleanPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    'SharePlace': './src/SharePlace.js',
    'MyPlace': './src/MyPlace.js',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist', 'assets', 'scripts'),
    publicPath: 'assets/scripts'
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              [
                '@babel/preset-env',
                { useBuiltIns: 'usage', corejs: { version: 3 } }
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [new CleanPlugin.CleanWebpackPlugin()]
};
```

> These are my Project files arrangement:-
> [image]

**Here is my html file of my project:-**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Share a Place</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles/share-place.css" />
    <script src="/src/SharePlace.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <template id="modal-template">
      <div class="backdrop"></div>
      <div class="modal"></div>
    </template>
    <template id="loading-modal-content">
      <div class="modal__content centered">
        <div class="lds-dual-ring"></div>
      </div>
    </template>

    <header>
      <h1>Share a Place!</h1>
    </header>

    <section id="selected-place">
      <div id="map">
        <p>
          You haven't selected any place yet. Please enter an address or locate
          yourself!
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section id="share-controls">
      <input
        id="share-link"
        type="text"
        readonly
        value="Select a place to get a sharable link."
      />
      <button id="share-btn" disabled>Share Place</button>
    </section>

    <section id="place-data">
      <form>
        <label for="address">Address</label>
        <input type="text" />
        <button type="submit">Find Place</button>
      </form>
      <button id="locate-btn">Get Current Location</button>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also that I have applied "type": "module" on Package.json file but my error never resolves. Can somebody please tell me what should I do to overcome this issue and how to resolve it for further work?

Comment: Your title says the error appears in Node.js, but in your text, you say "the problem occurs into the console browser". This code is purely front-end, this has nothing to do with Node.

Comment: is there any issue on module.exports code section?

Answer (score 0):

this is because by default node.js uses CommonJS which means you need to use `require` instead of `import`.

You can use `import` but you need to set your `package.json` to have `"type": "module"` this will also have an impact on code you load in and the way the rest of your code is structured.

For your own sanity, I would stick with the CommonJS paradigms when working with NodeJS

[Here's a good article on the differences](https://medium.com/computed-comparisons/commonjs-vs-amd-vs-requirejs-vs-es6-modules-2e814b114a0b#:%7E:text=The%20major%20difference%20arises%20in,uses%20just%20the%20exports%20variable.&text=The%20cons%20are%20just%20one,these%20modules%20directly%20without%20transpiling.)

Comment: can you tell me how to write require method for this code?